# IIT KAnpur phd entrance test paper 2017

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence $ (a_n)_{n= 1}^\infty$  defined by

$$a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} , &\text{if }n = 2^k,\quad k= 0,1,2,,,,\\ 0 ,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then   which of the following option is corrects

$a)$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$ but  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(na_n)$ doesnot
 exist

$b)$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is divergent  but $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(na_n)=0$

$c)$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty $ and $ (na_n)_{n= 1}^\infty$ has  subsequence  with limit $1$

$d)$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(na_n)=0$

My answer :  option C and option D ....$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$ that mean  $(a_n)$ is converge  and finite

Is it correct, or not ??

Any hints solutions/solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Your choice of (C,D) is not self-consistent: if $\lim na_n = 0$, $(na_n)_n$ cannot have a subsequence with limit 1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{2^k} $$ ..is clearly a convergent sum ($\lt\infty)$.

$$ n a_n = \begin{cases} 1 , &\text{if }n = 2^k,\quad k= 0,1,2,,,,\\ 0 ,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

...and this sequence has no limit for $n\to\infty$. But there is obviously a subsequence with limit equal to 1.

You can take it over from here.